# Storing upload file as binary data in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have been struggling with this issue. I'm trying to upload a file to the server and save it as binary data in the database.

I know how to upload a file to the server and it's working fine.

I need to know how to save the file as binary data in the database.

This is what I have accomplished:

In a SQL Server database, I have a table called `files` with the following columns:

```
Id, int, identity column 
FileName, nvarchar(50) 
UploadDate, datetime
FileContent, varbinary(max)
```

`HomeController.cs`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            // extract only the filename
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

            // extract the file content to byte array
            var content = new byte[file.ContentLength];
            // reads the content from stream
            file.InputStream.Read(content, 0, file.ContentLength);

            //get file extesion
            var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            //save file name as uniqe
            var uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            Files fu = new Files
            {
                FileName = uniqueFileName,
                UploadDate = DateTime.Now,
                FileContent = content
            };

            DB.Files.Add(fu);
            DB.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }

    // redirect back to the index action to show the form once again
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

`index.cshtml`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="files" multiple/>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

This code inserts a records into the database table, and the record looks like this:

```
Id  FileName                                UploadDate              FileContent
1   716d30a5-8019-4ec9-a5e9-5b3966296bfc    2015-11-27 21:50:27.037 <Binary data>
```

I don't know why the `fileContent` column gets filled with the text `<Binary data>`.

Comment: `InputStream.Read` does not work the way you think it works, you must use the retuned int and keep reading till you read the data fully.

Comment: That's how SQL Server shows binary data. Your data has not been magically converted to "Binary Data".

Comment: @ataravati , not everybody have 15 years of experience:) now i know.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since file content data type is binary, Sql server manage this as binary data type internally. You can not see the binary directly by looking into Table.

If you want to view Binary data in SSMS, give a try to [this](https://balajiramesh.wordpress.com/2008/03/10/convert-column-data-from-binary-to-string-with-sql-server-2005/)

This is a example to retrieve the binday data

```
// Assumes that connection is a valid SqlConnection object.
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
  "SELECT pub_id, logo FROM pub_info", connection);

// Writes the BLOB to a file (*.bmp).
FileStream stream;                          
// Streams the BLOB to the FileStream object.
BinaryWriter writer;                        

// Size of the BLOB buffer.
int bufferSize = 100;                   
// The BLOB byte[] buffer to be filled by GetBytes.
byte[] outByte = new byte[bufferSize];  
// The bytes returned from GetBytes.
long retval;                            
// The starting position in the BLOB output.
long startIndex = 0;                    

// The publisher id to use in the file name.
string pubID = "";                     

// Open the connection and read data into the DataReader.
connection.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);

while (reader.Read())
{
  // Get the publisher id, which must occur before getting the logo.
  pubID = reader.GetString(0);  

  // Create a file to hold the output.
  stream = new FileStream(
    "logo" + pubID + ".bmp", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
  writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);

  // Reset the starting byte for the new BLOB.
  startIndex = 0;

  // Read bytes into outByte[] and retain the number of bytes returned.
  retval = reader.GetBytes(1, startIndex, outByte, 0, bufferSize);

  // Continue while there are bytes beyond the size of the buffer.
  while (retval == bufferSize)
  {
    writer.Write(outByte);
    writer.Flush();

    // Reposition start index to end of last buffer and fill buffer.
    startIndex += bufferSize;
    retval = reader.GetBytes(1, startIndex, outByte, 0, bufferSize);
  }

  // Write the remaining buffer.
  writer.Write(outByte, 0, (int)retval - 1);
  writer.Flush();

  // Close the output file.
  writer.Close();
  stream.Close();
}

// Close the reader and the connection.
reader.Close();
connection.Close();
```

Source : [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87z0hy49(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: So, you say that the inserted data to the database is fine?

Comment: Yes, It is inserted, now you have to retrieve this.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87z0hy49(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i tried this: "SELECT sys.fn_sqlvarbasetostr(FileContent) From [dbo].[Files]" and the result was this- "Operand type clash: varbinary(max) is incompatible with sql_variant"